# Deleting a CommonJS module's cache doesn't deallocate its memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

I have a module called `array.js`:

```
module.export = Array(1e7).fill("memory memory memory")
```

In `mem.js` I require the above, delete its cache and require it again and again. I print out  `heapUsed` each time.

```
require("/home/me/array.js")
console.log(process.memoryUsage().heapUsed)

delete require.cache['/home/me/array.js']
require("/home/me/array.js")
console.log(process.memoryUsage().heapUsed)

delete require.cache['/home/me/array.js']
require("/home/me/array.js")
console.log(process.memoryUsage().heapUsed)

delete require.cache['/home/me/array.js']
require("/home/me/array.js")
console.log(process.memoryUsage().heapUsed)
```

The output is:

```
82379456
162686368
242700680
322703808
```

So the heap size increases despite the fact I've delete the module's cache and I have no references to it.

(Even if, at the end of the file, I add a timeout to give the GC more time to deallocate, and print the `heapUsed` later, it's still the same the previous `heapUsed`.)

Is this expected?

Is it possible to repeatedly require a module without keeping references to the previous require, ergo increasing the heap size.